# pthread_mutex_lock works only with sleep

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I pass a struct in pthread_create which contains a char* and I lock the main and the thread with mutexes so I can protect this string because when the second thread will be created the string will change and the first thread will use the second string and not the first. Here is the code:

main.c

```
while( th_num < th_size )
{   
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    received = 0;

    /* Read the desired readable size */
    if( read(newsock, &size, sizeof(size)) < 0 ) 
    { perror("Read"); exit(1); }

    /* Read all data */
    while( received < size )
    {
        if( (nread = read(newsock, buffer + received, size - received)) < 0 )
        { perror("Read"); exit(1); }

        received += nread;
    }

    printf("Received string: %s\n",buffer);


    Q->receiver = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(buffer)+1);
    strncpy(Q->receiver, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);

    if( (err = pthread_create(&thread_server[th_num], NULL, thread_start, (void*) Q)) == true )
    { show_error("pthread_create", err); }
    /* -------------------------------------------------- */


    th_num++;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    usleep(500);
}
```

pthread_server.c

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
/*
do some stuff here
*/
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

The program works fine but the problem is that it only works if I put usleep(500). My guess is that the thread cant lock the mutex in time so it needs sleep to do this right. Is there a way to do it without usleep()?

Comment: Without the sleep, almost the next instruction after the mutex unlock is a new mutex lock — so the mutex is locked almost all the time.  (There's a loop jump and test between the unlock and the lock, but that's all.)  That's always going to cause problems.  Mutexes must be held for the minimum possible time to prevent other threads being locked out.  You need to ensure that you can do useful work without holding the mutex.  The sleep, of course, gives other threads a chance to execute.

Comment: Thats the point here, when main unlocks the mutex the thread will lock it, so when the main will try to lock the mutex again it will stack untill the thread unlocks it. This helps me because i dont want the main to change the string before the first thread is done with it. I dont understand why is bad that the mutex is locked all the time?

Comment: Without the sleep, there's no way except by accident that a thread gets a chance to lock the mutex between the unlock and lock in the main code.  They're 'far apart' textually, but they are executed in very close sequence.  All that read and alloc stuff is time consuming.  You need to rethink what you're up to with that mutex.  There isn't enough code shown for us to get any idea what you're doing.  Those reads can hang indefinitely as far as we can see.  If you don't want the main program modifying the string, pass a copy of the string to the thread and the thread frees it.

Comment: Possibly better, have the thread do most of the work that's currently in the main code.  You have to make sure that things can work in parallel; otherwise, there's no benefit to threading.

Comment: So the only way to work with mutexes is with sleep?

Comment: No.  The way to work with mutexes is to make sure that all the processes that need to use the protected resource do so for as little time as possible, and do as much work as possible without needing a mutex.  You use a mutex to protect shared data.  With threading, you want as little shared data as possible, so there is as little need to use mutexes as possible.  Your code is not minimizing the scope of the locking; it is the whole body of the main loop that is locked.  If your thread first attempts to lock the mutex, it can't do anything until the main thread unlocks it.

Comment: Technically, if OP wishes that the second thread will start and finish between loop iterations, OP should've just put a regular call there. There's not enough code for us to judge why a mutex and a multithreaded solution is needed, so we can't suggest anything better

Comment: I concur with Mark. To that point, I see no sense in a mutex in *any* of this. That loop simply looks to be pulling a size, then some data, from a socket. Surely you don't intend to do *that* on a stack of threads and the *same* socket concurrently. Rather, it appears you want to do that to acquire a buffer to process, then send that buffer (via some mystery structure `Q`) to some thread launched shortly thereafter for processing. Even `buffer` doesn't seem to be mandatory as shared between threads. You could just as well get the `size`, allocate `Q->receiver`, read into *that*, etc.

Comment: I havent show all the code of course, this is just a sample. Its an assignment for my class, a client connects with server(which is the main.c) and then the server takes the string from client and have to create a thread who will connect to another thread. I have to pass this string inside a structure because i need a structure inside the thread. The problem is that it works only with sleep, otherwise the thread will take the same string.

Comment: There is and another way of course. I want the struct to be the same in all threads, so i can use shared memory but i dont know how to do this yet so i preferred to avoid it but it seems that this is the best choice. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Small observation if it'll make a difference. Is there a reason why you didn't wrap the entire while loop with the mutex? Within your mutex, `th_num` becomes modified ultimately affecting the condition on the while loop that other threads could potentially evaluate resulting in an undesired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I don't understand why you need to call `pthread_create();` in a mutual exclusion portion of code, your problems is:

you use threads but the flow of your program is approaching to be sequential because of the large mutual exclusion portion of code.

Let X a generic thread in your program.

Without the `usleep(500);` when the X thread finish it releases the mutex with `pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);` but afterwards the thread X reacquires the lock so no one else can access in the mutual exclusion portion of code.

Now I don't know what your shared data is, so I can only suggest you:

1) Reduce the mutual exclusion portion of code, only use it when you access to a shared data;

2) Rethink about your program structure.